# Wall visible after light source removed

Tags: visible-light

Let's say you have a lamp pointed at a wall, in a dark room with no other light source, if you turned off that lamp

## Would the wall still be visible for any amount of time?

Comment: what object?  You mean the wall?  Yes.  Light has a finite velocity.

Comment: @Nic yes, I meant the wall. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visible needs a definition. As the velocity of light is practically 300.000.000 meters per second and the distance to the wall maybe 1 meter it will be visible for the order of (1/3)*10^-8 seconds, considering the light source will have some spread. Not visible for the human eye except as an [after image on the retina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterimage), if the light is strong enough.

The energy will turn into thermal energy of the wall. If the wall were painted with [phosphorescent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence) paint or a [photoluminescent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoluminescence) paint then it might be visible from minutes to hours.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your light source is Beta Centauri.  Turn off the star and the wall will continue to be illuminated for 350 years.

Answer number two:  the wall is always visible in the infrared.

Answer number 3:  never mind... anna v beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

When the light goes out, there is a stream of photons in the "pipeline", travelling from the source to the wall, and then to the observer's eye. The wall will be visible until the last photon finishes it's trip.  Light goes about a foot per nanosecond.  Do the math...

Answer (score 0):

Yes because whatever light you are using, the radiating element will be still a bit excited, therefore "illuminating" (very tiny bit, but still...)